# How to iterate the flashvars?(Actionscript)

Tags: flash, actionscript

What construction i need to use, for in, or for?

```
var params = stage.loaderInfo.parameters;

    for (var i in params) 
    { 
       // trace(params[i]);
       // or
       // var test = params[i];
    }
```

how to do it, to get all the values?

ps: params.length - show the number of flashvars?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a **for-in** or **for-each-in** loop. For-in will iterate over the keys, while for-each-in will iterate over the values. A for-in loop is probably what you want, if you want to get both the keys and values.

For example, if your flashVars look something like this:

```
{ userId: 100, userName: 'Mister PHP' }
```

A for-in loop would look something like this:

```
var flashVars:Object = stage.loaderInfo.parameters;

for (var key:String in flashVars) {
    var value:String = flashVars[key] as String;
    trace(key + ' = ' + value);
}

// output:
// userId = 100;
// userName = Mister PHP
```

While a for-each-in loop would look like:

```
var flashVars:Object = stage.loaderInfo.parameters;

for each (var value:String in flashVars) {
    trace(value);
}

// output:
// 100
// Mister PHP
```

As far as I know, there is no easy way to get the length of an object or dictionary. You would have to iterate through the object and increment a counter on each pass.

Here's a [reference on loops in ActionScript](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fcf.html)